# How to average a column in a text file without using ' character?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, perl

I need to do it without using the `'` character.

I could do it like this:

```
awk '{sum+=$5} END { print "Average = ",sum/NR}'
```

except this contains a  `'`.

Comment: Can you give an example input and the expected output? What is the problem with the `'`?

Comment: Why can't you use single quotes?

Comment: "first column" vs `$5` ?

Comment: This reads very much like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)...

Comment: I will upvote the question, if you tell me why.

Comment: a script was echoed with 'script blabla' to a file that needed this part between the ' ' 's, that's why. But I don't understand why is that important..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `''` (strong quotes), you can use the weaker form `""`, except you then need to escape the `"`s.

`awk "{sum+=\$5} END { print \"Average = \",sum/NR}"`

But why?

Comment: `$5` will expand here, which is probably not what you want -- it needs to be escaped. I don't really understand what the problem the OP is having is though.

Comment: Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell supports it, you could use a *here document* to read the commands from standard input, with a quoted delimiter to prevent shell expansion of the awk variable `$5`

```
awk -f- somefile << "EOF"
{sum+=$5} END { print "Average = ",sum/NR}
EOF
```

Or just put the commands in a file and run *that* with `awk -f`.